# Dealing a Random Hand of 5 Cards in Poker

Tags: java, arraylist

so as by the title of this, I need to deal a random hand of 5 cards to simulate a poker game.  I also must arrange things so that the hand cannot contain the same card more than once.  This is what I have so far:

```
public static ArrayList<Card> makeDeck()
{
      ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>( 52 ); 
    String[] suits = 
        { "spades", "hearts", "diamonds", "clubs" }; 

    for ( String suit : suits ) 
    { 
      for ( int k = 2 ; k <= 14 ; k++ ) 
      { 
        deck.add( new Card( suit, k ) ); 
      } 
    } 
    return deck;
}

public static ArrayList<Card> dealHand( ArrayList<Card> deck )
{
  ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>(5);
  Random rc = new Random();
  for ( int j = 0; j <= hand.size(); j++)
  {
      hand.add(rc.nextInt(deck.size()));
  }
   return hand;

}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
  System.out.println(dealHand());
}
```

I'm receiving an error message saying: MainClass.java:38: error: no suitable method found for add(int)

```
  hand.add(rc.nextInt(deck.size()));
```

If somebody could please explain to me how I could fix this error it'd be very helpful, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just creating a random number and adding it to your hand. I presume you want to get the `Card` that represents and add that to the hand instead.

Try this:

```
int cardNumber = rc.nextInt(deck.size());
Card card = deck.remove(cardNumber);
hand.add(card);
```

I've made that a bit more verbose than needed, for clarity. This can be done in one line if you need to:

```
hand.add(deck.remove(rc.nextInt(deck.size())));
```

Note the use of `remove()` from the deck instead of `get()` or you will run the risk of dealing the same card twice (or more).

**Edit** given your comment: Yes, you need to change how this is called in `main()`:

```
System.out.println(dealHand(makeDeck()));
```

You weren't passing the deck into `dealHand()`.

**Edit 2** OH! Ha, I figured it out. Check out your loop, it adds one to the hand size so the loop never terminates and the deck runs out of cards.

Change

```
for ( int j = 0; j <= hand.size(); j++)
```

To

```
for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++) // Note less-than, not less-than-or-equal-to
```

It might also be worth considering making the hand size an argument to `makeHand()` and using that to pre-allocate the `ArrayList` and drive this loop instead of depending on the "magic number" 5.

Comment: Awesome, this has cleared that issue, but now it's telling me that within the main method: method dealHand in class MainClass cannot be applied to given types; 

  System.out.println(dealHand());
(If you need to see the rest of the Card constructor, I'll add that in)

Comment: Okay, thank you.  Unfortunately, it's now giving me the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive 

at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388) 

at MainClass.dealHand(MainClass.java:38)  :/

Comment: OK! I think we've got it now.

Comment: There we go, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
hand.add(rc.nextInt(deck.size()));
```

to

```
hand.add(deck.get(rc.nextInt(deck.size())));
```